# cakePHP :Find all query conditions questions

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to format a find condition to generate a set of data to be later printed to an excel view via PhPExcel. The intended functionality is that if the start_date and the end_date fields match for the entry, the entry is included in the array. If the fields do not match, it's excluded.

```
    $my_data = $this-> RecordsMaster-> find("all", array(
        'conditions' => array(
            "RecordsMaster.start_date" == "RecordsMaster end_date"
        )
    ));
```

The problem lies in the fact that the statement above doesn't actually do anything. Rows from mySQL table with start and end dates that differ are included in the data dump to excel.

Comment: and where's the problem? you get an error message? :) please complete your question

Comment: Sorry, ran out of coffee today at the office. :P

Comment: Im surprised you didn't get an error relating to your use of == as the array key value terminator. You may want to look at this: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lucaswxp/2011/02/11/easy_and_simple_subquery_cakephp

Answer (score 2):

### The conditions in the question don't mean much

The conditions in the question are equivalent to:

```
$my_data = $this-> RecordsMaster-> find("all", array(
    'conditions' => array(
        false
    )
));
```

Which will return no records, since it will generate the following sql:

```
WHERE 0;
```

### Don't use key => value to match fields

Correcting the typos in the code in the question would still not generate desired sql - it would generate:

```
WHERE `RecordsMaster`.`start_date` = "RecordsMaster end_date"
```

I.e. where `start_date` is that litteral string.

> The intended functionality is that if the start_date and the end_date fields match for the entry

To generate `WHERE field = otherfield` you can specify as a string:

```
$my_data = $this-> RecordsMaster-> find("all", array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "RecordsMaster.start_date = RecordsMaster.end_date"
    )
));
```